# bisect_left on first item of list within list, Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, binary-search

I have a list like this for example:

```
L = [(0, "test", "value"), (0, "test2", "value2")]
```

and I need to = bisect_left the first item of each tuple to find an index in the list. However, I can't think of a way of doing this without creating a list of all of these first items before hand:

`exampleList = [L[i][0] for i in range(len(L))]`

any ideas on another way to do this as it works but when my list gets to 5000 items long it is very slow and I need a faster way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import bisect
L = [(0, "test", "value"), (1, "test2", "value2"),(3,"test3","value3")]
print (bisect.bisect_left(L,(2,)))
```

python deals with tuple comparisons great... just pass it `(2,"asd","dsa")` or even just `(2,)` (or whatever your index location item you are trying to find)

or you could pass it `(0,"asd","value")` and it would know to put it to the left of the other `(0,"test","value")` item tuple ... or `(0,"zzzz","value")` and it would know to put it to the right of that item

Answer (score 6):

Python has a builtin [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left), you can use it.  You don't need to build the whole intermediate list, you just need a lazy object that retrieves the first item from the tuple at that position.

Something simple like:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return L[item][0]
```

Beginning with Python 3.10's `bisect` you can [use a key function for the search](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/871934d4cf00687b3d1411c6e344af311646c1ae), so a wrapper is no longer required.  In your case it would be `key=operator.itemgetter(0)`.

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [(0, "test1", "value1"), (1, "test2", "value2"), (3, "test3", "value3")]
```

From Python 3.10

```
print(bisect_left(L, 4, key = itemgetter(0))) # output : 3
```

For below Python 3.10 another way is to use zip function

```
a, _, _ = zip(*L)

print(bisect_left(a, 2)) # output : 2
print(bisect_left(a, 4)) # output : 3
```